# Protect content of certain cells without protecting worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

We have a excel 2016 workbook with multiple tabs, each tab is dedicated to a specific sales person. Each salespeep, logins from a form, and his (only his) worksheet is unlocked and allow for editing.

A table is present showing his past data.  He is allowed to update or change most of his data in the table. He updates specific cells, saves and closes then workbook. the wb closing process, relocks his sheet.  Before he leaves, he can look at other salespeeps sheets but cannot edit because they are locked.

Now the rub. On each of the salespeeps sheets, certain columns (the same for all peeps) contain data entered by an admin.  This data must be seen by the salespeeps but must not be altered.

Any thoughts on how to protect certain columns from existing content change on an unprotected worksheet.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't just lock those columns?

Comment: @Dave I do understand why they don't just lock those coluims. Currently they have locked all cells from altering and protect the worksheet. The macro unlocks it with password, so all on that worksheet becomes available. The macro would now have to set all editable cells to unlocked and relock the sheet, and reverse it on closing. Thats not easy to do. But I think it is possible to select all cells that can be lockable, assign it to a range, and from the VBA code use range("name of range" to mass lock/unlock.

Comment: hmmm, then the question is why this is required? For accidental use? If so, simply have a macro which fires on worksheet_changed, if the cell is a given column simply return and don't allow the change! If each user has a "role" then this is easy to do , but worse case is the admin team just disable that macro when they need to make a change and re-enable later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the VBA code, it is hard to determine how the locking/unlocking occurs. I assume it is done by setting the `locked` attribute for a cell, and using the worksheet protect and unprotect feature.

What you would need to do, is select all the sells that are allowed for editing, and create a Custom Range for them. I don't have excel handy, but I believe it is `Data` > `Define Custom Range` From the same location you can select a range, which will automatically select the cells in Excel.

Alternatively to working with custom ranges, you can select the necessary columns, given that the admin data is not on the same column. That would allow an `activesheet.range("K:L").select` to be possible.

In the VBA code, after unlocking the worksheet, it has to select this range and alter the `locked` setting for these cells, then protect the sheet again. The reverse has to be done upon exiting (unprotect, set all locked, protect).

To find out the proper VBA code, perform the action manually while recording to a macro and copy the code.

Comment: you are spot on with the concept. we lock the worksheet so other sales persons cant change content on other sales persons tabs. if we set the lock attr of cells that are allowed to be changed and then lock the sheets to take effect, then any sales person can change anything with the lock attr not set. defeats purpose.  I will examine the custom range concept. thanks for your help

Comment: You've misunderstood me here. the idea is that you lock it back to the previous state upon closing the sheet. If you really can't change the locking state, you may want to try adding an invisible object over the cells that you want to protect. Its a dummy protection though, but it will give people the impression they cannot click the cells. If they really want, they can use the cell selector in the upper left or the arrow keys to still get to the cells though.

Answer (score 0):

LPChip put me on the right path and I thank you much.  The process I used is as follows:

1. on the sales person sheet, set lock attr for the whole sheet as false
2. on the table for that sales person, set the lock attr for the complete table as true
3. We created a custom range, as LPChip suggested, of all columns that we did not to be editable by anyone. Did this manually and assigned a range name (LockedColumns).
4. then protected the sheet
   this is the starting condition for this sheet and all the other sales peeps sheets.
5. Sales person logs on and with correct credentials, is taken to his/her sheet where the following takes place in vba code behind the scene:

   - We select the table and set the lock attr to false
   - We select the Range.("LockedColumns").select and set the lock attr to true
   - We protect the worksheet.

This allows the authorized salespeep to enter data into the cells we allow and prevents them from changing data in the cells we do not want changes in.  The sales person can look at other sales tabs but not modify.  When sales peep logs off or workbook closes, we capture before close and in vba code, 1. select full table again, set the lock attr to true and then protect the worksheet. We save and then redirect back to menu tab for next user.

I was stumped and LP opened my eyes. Thanks you again.

Comment: This was exactly what I meant. :) Glad it worked out.